# Spreadsheets adding an apostrophe to some dates

Tags: excel, date, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

The same issue is happening in both Excel and LibreOffice Calc.

I have a spreadsheet with a date column formatted to English/Australia (DD/MM/YYYY).
For some dates, there is an apostrophe added to the start: '06/01/2020. (No idea why, seems to auto format some).

This is causing issues in an application I'm trying to import the spreadsheet into.

1. If I try to manually remove the apostrophe, the date switches to US (01/06/2020). Obviously not helpful, as this will cause the imported date to switch from Jan to June.
2. I have tried to do a FIND/REPLACE for "'", but for some reason nothing is found.

I have Googled around, but cannot find anything. If anyone has any idea on a solution, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Is `06/01/2020` an actual example of a date to which the apostrophe is prepended?  Or is the actual date something different?  How did these dates get into the worksheet to start with?  If they were imported from a text or csv file, you most likely did not set the date parameter correctly when importing.

Comment: The leading apostrophe is documented extensively on this site and Google.  Yet it remains notorious for causing problems among the uninitiated who may go for years without realizing they are causing their own problem by opening a CSV via double click without ever properly importing it. @Ron is 100% correct in what is "most likely" the problem; it may not be your problem, but the chances significantly stacked in favor.  I explain in more detail in this gratuitous self link https://superuser.com/questions/1487086/i-know-how-to-fix-excel-dates-stored-as-text-but-why-does-it-happen/1487309#1487309

Comment: Oh, one more thing about that leading apostrophe. This may help you understand why you haven't been finding them.  When you have an opportunity; find an empty cell, select it, place one apostrophe in the cell, and watch the cell as you press enter. 
Now reselect the cell and compare the text in the formula bar to the text you see in the cell. For another kick in the pants, add one more apostrophe to same cell and see if you note a difference.   Now try adding two. 
Did your observations match your explanations? There's a whole leading apostrophe meta world just waiting for you to explore.

Comment: Easy route to fix this is to use `Text To Columns` feature if the whole contains dates conforming to DD/MM/YYYY. Select the column, choose `Text To Columns` and then use delimited option (delimiter as apostrophe ') and then use `DMY` switch in dates option.

Comment: Thank you @ProfoundlyOblivious & Ron Rosenfeld - Opening a blank spreadsheet an importing the CSV completely resolved this.

Comment: This solution only works if you have the opportunity to import the csv yourself.  What can I do if I get the spreadsheet where a csv has already been imported? The answer enables one to avoid the issue, but not how to solve the issue once you're already troubled with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ProfoundlyOblivious & @Ron Rosenfeld the solution that worked was to open a blank spreadsheet and import the data, rather than open it directly (double clicking the file).